# How to override css cursor property of a hovered button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I have a `<button>`, when the user hover it, the cursor become pointer (via CSS).

When the user click on the `<button>`, the cursor of all the page should become `wait` (via jQuery).

However, if the user keeps the cursor inside `<button>`, it will stay as `pointer`. How can I fix this ?

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/URuLa/

Tested with Chrome 36.0.1985.125 (last version)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a class for html that sets the cursor and sets all elements to also have the wait cursor when html has that class

CSS

```
html.wait, html.wait * {
   cursor:wait;
}
```

then instead of doing

```
$('html').css("cursor","wait");
```

use addClass to add the **wait** class to html

```
$('html').addClass("wait");
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/URuLa/2/)

Then when done just use removeClass to remove the class

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cursor property for your button in the `click` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        $('html').css('cursor','wait');
        $(this).css('cursor','wait');
    });
});
```